# Are there myths that contains the concept that people with triple iris eyes are psychic or clairvoyant?

Tags: folklore

I have heard that those with triple iris eyes were said to be psychic, clairvoyant, etc.  Is this true if so in what myths does this concept appear.

Answer (score 3):

I think the idea that [polycoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycoria) is linked to special powers must be rather widespread.

Apart from the "third eye" of Indian tradition, we find in Irish tradition the hero Cú Chulainn has multiple pupils.  According to [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Cu-Chulainn): "His prowess was increased by the gift of seven fingers on each hand, seven toes on each foot, and seven pupils in each eye."  It's been a while since I read the Ulster Cycle, but I don't recall him being clairvoyant or psychic per se. He certainly exhibited great physical strength, endurance, agility and beauty beyond that of most other men.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you mean the concept of the [Third Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_eye), which originated in Hindu mythology.

The third eye (also called the mind's eye, or inner eye) is a mystical and esoteric concept of a speculative invisible eye, usually depicted as located on the forehead, which provides perception beyond ordinary sight.

Paraphrasing the Rig Veda:

> After the death of his lover Sati, Shiva withdrew from all society and
>   in pain, he started to meditate. His meditation was so deep that the
>   other gods could not wake him, even after Sati was reborn as Parvati.
>
> Finally, the gods sent Kama, the god of love, to wake Shiva. Kama
>   thought that using one of his arrows would do the trick but after the
>   arrow struck Shiva, the third eye opened up and sent a flame engulfing
>   Kama.
>
> When Shiva’s meditation was broken, he did experience desire for
>   Parvati but instead of letting his desire win, Shiva’s anger became
>   greater and a third eye opened up in his forehead.

Answer (score 1):

I've just started reading the Ulster cycle as well and a young girl named fedelm with a triple iris looks into the future for medb

Answer (score 0):

There is a very powerful Chinese deity who has three eyes: 杨戬. His third eye is called 天眼, which represents insight.

And if you means multi pupils in one eye, 重瞳 is known as a symbol of born sage.

I use google translate and hope nothing too serious wrong :P

Comment: Thanks for this perspective. Do you have any sources for these? Thanks!